# How to order result by the variable from the CASE statement

Tags: mysql

How to order results by the variable `promotion_price` which is from the `CASE` statement. What I get as error is:

```
Unknown column 'promotion_price' in 'where clause'
```

And this is my query:

```
SELECT product.*,
    CASE
        WHEN promotion.type=1 THEN product.price - (product.price * promotion.value/100)
        WHEN promotion.type=2 THEN product.price - promotion.value
        ELSE product.price
    END promotion_price
FROM product LEFT JOIN page ON product.category_id=page.id
LEFT JOIN promotion_product ON product.id=promotion_product.main_product_id
LEFT JOIN promotion ON promotion_product.promo_id=promotion.id 
WHERE (page.id = 12 OR page.id_in = 12) 
AND promotion_price >= 49.50 
AND promotion_price <= 108.89
GROUP BY product.id
ORDER BY  promotion_price ASC
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use  a column alias in where condition  you must repeat the code

```
SELECT product.*,
    CASE
        WHEN promotion.type=1 THEN product.price - (product.price * promotion.value/100)
        WHEN promotion.type=2 THEN product.price - promotion.value
        ELSE product.price
    END promotion_price
FROM product LEFT JOIN page ON product.category_id=page.id
LEFT JOIN promotion_product ON product.id=promotion_product.main_product_id
LEFT JOIN promotion ON promotion_product.promo_id=promotion.id 
WHERE (page.id = 12 OR page.id_in = 12) 
AND (CASE
        WHEN promotion.type=1 THEN product.price - (product.price * promotion.value/100)
        WHEN promotion.type=2 THEN product.price - promotion.value
        ELSE product.price
    END ) >= 49.50 
AND (CASE
        WHEN promotion.type=1 THEN product.price - (product.price * promotion.value/100)
        WHEN promotion.type=2 THEN product.price - promotion.value
        ELSE product.price
    END) <= 108.89
GROUP BY product.id
ORDER BY  promotion_price ASC
```

the where condition is evaluated  before the evaluation of the select column alias so in the moment of evaluation of the where condition the select column alias  are not know to query engine

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: Just a little extra question. Does repeating the `CASE` part affects the performance ?

Comment: not to much  .. the main perfomance issue is related  the the data retrieve  and this is optimized  for all the same case..  the time expended  for strict parse is a minor part ..  hope is clear  ..  otherwise  .. ask me for specific detail

Comment: Just to not wasting your time. Can you point me some useful article to read about it because I am not pretty sure what should I search in google :) . Thank you again!

Comment: Then main  "article" is the DB docs https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization.html  useful is also  the pdf as  this https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/presentations/mysql-performance-tuning101/  you can sign in for free on mylsq/oracle docs  ...account .. i periodically review the mysql optimization docs  .. for a mind refresh

Answer (score 1):

As we know, we can't use the inline column in where clause in single SQL, you can try the below one with subquery.

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         CASE
            WHEN promotion.type = 1 
               THEN product.price - (product.price * promotion.value/100)
            WHEN promotion.type = 2 
               THEN product.price - promotion.value
            ELSE product.price
        END promotion_price,
        product.*
    FROM
        product 
    LEFT JOIN 
        page ON product.category_id = page.id
    LEFT JOIN 
        promotion_product ON product.id = promotion_product.main_product_id
    LEFT JOIN 
        promotion ON promotion_product.promo_id = promotion.id 
    WHERE 
        (page.id = 12 OR page.id_in = 12)
    GROUP BY 
        product.id) s
WHERE
    promotion_price >= 49.50 
    AND promotion_price <= 108.89
ORDER BY  
    promotion_price ASC
```